# Python: how to plot points with little overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, overlapping

I am using python to plot points. The plot shows relationship between area and the # of points of interest (POIs) in this area. I have 3000 area values and 3000 # of POI values.

Now the plot looks like this:
[image]

The problem is that, at lower left side, points are severely overlapping each other so it is hard to get enough information. Most areas are not that big and they don't have many POIs.

I want to make a plot with little overlapping. I am wondering whether I can use unevenly distributed axis or use histogram to make a beautiful plot. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can also use transparancy (keyword argument `alpha` in `plt.plot`) to visualize the density of the points.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have two major choices here. First adjusting this plot, and second choosing to display your data in another type of plot.

In the first option, I would suggest clipping the boundries. You have plenty of space around the borders. If you limit the plot to the boundries, your data would scale better. On top of it, you may choose to plot the points with smaller dots, so that they would seem less overlapping.

Second option would be to choose displaying data in a different view, such as histograms. This might give a better insight in terms of distribution of your data among different bins. But this would be completely different type of view, in regards to the former plot.

I would suggest trying to adjust the plot by limiting the boundries of the plot to the data points, so that the plot area would have enough space to scale the data and try using histograms later. But as I mentioned, these are two different things and would give different insights about your data.

For adjusting you might try this:

```
x1,x2,y1,y2 = plt.axis()

plt.axis((x1,x2,y1,y2))
```

You would probably need to make minor adjustments to the axis variables. Note that there should definetly be better options instead of this, but this was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I also have another problem: now my x-axis is separated evenly by every 500, I want to make it like x-axis = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000,2500], and each interval has the same length on the plot. Any idea?

Comment: Well, you might accomplish something like that but I guess it would require some effort. Easiest would be to use a log scale such as plt.xscale('log')

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a logarithmic scale for the y axis. You can either use `pyplot.semilogy(...)` or `pyplot.yscale('log')` (http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html).

Note that points where `area <= 0` will not be rendered.

Comment: thanks for your answer! log really helps. I also have another problem: now my x-axis is separated evenly by every 500, I want to make it like x-axis = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000,2500], and each interval has the same length on the plot. Any idea?

Comment: What you want is possible but not conventional. I would not do that if I were you. Instead, I would make the plot the way you have with x-axis going from 0 to 2500, evenly-spaced every 500. Then, I would add (inside your existing axes) a small zoomed in version of the plot that only goes from x=0 to 500. See this link for an example on how to add a small plot inside another one (http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axes_demo.html)